# Downloading Images with Python aiohttp: ClientPayloadError: Response payload is not completed

Tags: python, aiohttp

Prerequisites:

- Python 3.9.5
- aiohttp 3.7.4.post0

Hello! I am trying to download images from the given URL, and 99% of the time it works just fine, here is the snippet:

```
async def download_image(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                raise exceptions.FileNotFound()
            data = await response.read()
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
            return img
```

But sometimes, on the step `data = await resp.read()` function throws `aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: Response payload is not completed`. Exception can be raised on a certain image, and on the second attempt to load this exact image it works again.

aiohttp documentation states:

> This exception can only be raised while reading the response payload
> if one of these errors occurs:
>
> - invalid compression
> - malformed chunked encoding
> - not enough data that satisfy Content-Length HTTP header.

What can I do to debug precisely what raises an exception? For me it seems some data in the process of `session.get(url)` gets corrupted, bits flip here and there. Is there a better way to retry image download than catching error while calling download_image function and repeating it?

Comment: We tried to debug this 6 months ago and we got nowhere. The only logical explanation, for us, was the malformed chunked encoding. We simply made a retry variable with a default value, then catch the error and rerun the request until it's satisfied with a await asyncio.sleep(random). After that we've not seen any problems.